# How to ask Spring Tool Suite (sts) to run a web application using Firefox?

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I am using Spring Tool Suite (sts) to develop a web application. When I test it by clicking "Run on Server", the Spring suite will open an IE inside its internal window area to run my application.

Can anyone tell me how to change the run property so that I can run my program using Firefox? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can configure that in the preferences. Go to "General -> Web Browser", select External Browser, and Firefox - and you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using "Spring Tool Suite 4"

Version: 4.9.0.RELEASE

You click: Window -> Reference -> (search Browser)

Choose the browser you want to build the project.
[image: Window -> Reference -> (search Browser ..)]